# How to build job in nodejs for asynchronous api requests

Tags: node.js, ajax, api, web-services, asynchronous

I want to build Service/Job with Node js that creates about 12 asynchronous requests every  1.5 second and collects data in order to return it to client.
Trying to do it on client side I got this kind of error from Chrome "net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES".
Thank you  in advance.

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` or `cron` module.

Comment: Using cron do I need to create 12 schedules or one schedule and create 12 api requests into it?

Comment: Of course, you can do it whatever you want in each execution